# .Net Web Api : consistent Json deserialization strategy between the API and a file upload?

Tags: asp.net, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I have a Asp.Net 6+ Web Api that has **two endpoints doing almost exactly the same thing :**

**- the first one** gets its parameters **automagically from Asp.Net** . I didn't give it a second thought: it accepts parameters from the POST's body and it's Asp.Net that does the deserialization, via System.Text.Json internally.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("public/v1/myRoute/")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Import(IEnumerable<JsonItemModel> items) {

        // the items are already ready to use.
        FooProcessItems(items);
    }
```

**- the second one** receives an IFormFile in a form data (the end-user uploads a file by using a button in the UI), gets the stream, and **deserializes** it "manually" using System.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("public/v1/myRouteWithFile/")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> ImportWithFile([FromForm] MyFormData formData
    ) {
       var stream = formaData.File.OpenReadStream();
       var items = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<JsonItemModel>>(file);
       FooProcessItems(items);
    }
```

**My question :**

I want to customize the deserialization process (to add some constraints such as "this field cannot be null", etc.) and I want both methods to produce **exactly the same result.**

How do I do that?

Is it simply a case of adding Json decorators in the model and letting .Net do the rest?

```
public class JsonItemModel {

    [JsonNumberHandling(JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString)] // <-- Some custom constraint that will be picked up both by Deserialize and the POST endpoint.
    public int SomeField { get; init; } = 0;

    ...
}
```